# "shutdown: failed to start child: DBConnection.Ownership.Manager" after updating library from Ecto 1 to Ecto 2

Tags: elixir, ecto, postgrex

I have [a library](https://github.com/henrik/ectoo) that uses Ecto and Postgrex (Postgrex is only used in tests).

After upgrading from Ecto 1 to Ecto 2, the test suite started giving this error:

```
$ mix test
Compiling 4 files (.ex)
Generated ectoo app
** (EXIT from #PID<0.46.0>) shutdown: failed to start child: DBConnection.Ownership.Manager
    ** (EXIT) exited in: GenServer.call(DBConnection.Ownership.PoolSupervisor, {:start_child, [#PID<0.175.0>, Postgrex.Protocol, [pool: DBConnection.Poolboy, types: true, hostname: "localhost", types: true, otp_app: :ectoo, repo: Ectoo.Repo, adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres, database: "ectoo_test", username: "henrik", pool_timeout: 5000, timeout: 15000, adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres, database: "ectoo_test", username: "henrik", extensions: [{Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.DateTime, []}, {Postgrex.Extensions.JSON, [library: nil]}], port: 5432]]}, :infinity)
        ** (EXIT) no process
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by making sure the `postgrex` app is running when the tests run.

In mix.exs:

```
def application do
  [applications: applications(Mix.env)]
end

defp applications(:test), do: [:logger, :postgrex]
defp applications(_), do: [:logger]
```